# "superiors" package breaks symbolic footnote position in Libertine

Tags: fonts, footnotes, superscripts, libertine

I want to use symbolic footnotes in one or two places of a document typeset in Libertine, the rest can stay arabic as usual.  Therefore, I redefine `\thefootnote` locally:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{libertine}
% \usepackage{superiors}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
  bla sldk slkd lskd\footnote{sldfkjlsdkfj sldksl dksld }
\end{center}

sld sldkjsl djfls djs d\footnote{sldfjslk}

\end{document}
```

Without `superiors`, everything is good (albeit the `2` is typographically inferior):

[image: OK footnote marks]

But unfortunately, once the one line is uncommented, the asterisk is badly positioned:

[image: not so OK asterisk]

The same effect occurs in the actual footnote Most times), and with subsequent symbols (dagger etc.)

I can see that [`superiors` redefines the footnotes](https://mirror.easyname.at/ctan/fonts/superiors/tex/superiors.sty) in some way, but don't really understand those internals.  How can I fix this error, keeping the `superiors` effect?  (Ideally, I'd also prefer the asterisk a bit larger than it appears in the first screenshot, but that's luxury).

---

### Post hoc

Given Ulrike's answer, I factored out the functionality into an environment to correctly switch to symbolic footnotes locally, starting from `*` every time and preserving the original numbering afterwards:

```latex
\newcounter{phg@footnotestate}
\newenvironment{symbolicfootnotes}{%
  \setcounter{phg@footnotestate}{\value{footnote}}%
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
  \renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}%
  % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/565263/46356
  \makeatletter\def\f@@tn@te{blub}\makeatother%
}{%
  \setcounter{footnote}{\value{phg@footnotestate}}%
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fool superiors by redefining `\f@@tn@te`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{superiors}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
 \renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}%
 \makeatletter\def\f@@tn@te{blub}\makeatother
  bla sldk slkd lskd\footnote{sldfkjlsdkfj sldksl dksld }
\end{center}

sld sldkjsl djfls djs d\footnote{sldfjslk}

\end{document}
```

[image]